# How to make a filter with condition in PHP MYSQL

Tags: php

how can I add a condition in my `SELECT` statement where whenever the count is one the one with the concatinated condition will be used. This is my code.

```
$done = "SELECT * FROM tbl_accepted WHERE status ='done'" ;
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
   $search_term = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['searchbox']);
   $done .= "AND acceptCarOwner = '{$search_term}'" ;
   $done .= "AND renter = '{$search_term}'";
}
$donequery = mysqli_query($db, $done);
```

What I want to happen is when a user search something on one field if the `$search_term` is not in the `AND acceptCarOwner = '{$search_term}'` condition it will go to the next condition which is `AND renter = '{$search_term}'`

Comment: Please come with the clear question.

Comment: @PranavMS - What I want to happen is that when the `SELECT` statement with the concatinated condition has values and the one that has values will be printed.

Comment: still need some more clarification or show some code effort

Comment: @PranavMS - updated sir I hope this time it can be understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter your data by concatenating your coditions. Give it a try.

```
$where = " `status` = 'done' ";

if(isset($_POST['search'])){
   $search_term = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['searchbox']);
   $where.= " AND `acceptCarOwner` = '{$search_term}'" ;
   $where.= " AND `renter` = '{$search_term}'";
}

$done = "SELECT * FROM tbl_accepted WHERE ". $where ;
$donequery = mysqli_query($db, $done);
```

Comment: How to know sir if the one `$where` has value?

Comment: I've done it sir! This answer helped me alot. I just made some changes and its good. Thanks!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

you use $_POST['search'] and then use $_POST['searchbox'] in next line

```
$done = "SELECT * FROM tbl_accepted WHERE status ='done'" ;
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
   $search_term = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['search']);
   $done .= "AND acceptCarOwner = '$search_term'" ;
   $done .= "AND renter = '$search_term'";
}
$donequery = mysqli_query($db, $done);
```